# Java resize an image

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I would like to display an image in an area in my Jframe but the image takes up much space.

I would like to take it fair precise dimensions.
How can I do this in Java

This is my simple code :

I am open to any proposal if I did not use the right method or the right class to instantiate the image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExempleDeplace extends JFrame{

    private JLabel myLabel;

    public ExempleDeplace(){
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         setTitle("Fenetre, modele Duchi");
         setSize(500,700);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         JLabel j = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/images/bateau.png"));
         add(j);
         setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {    
          ExempleDeplace c = new ExempleDeplace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ImageIO` to load your image as an Image first, then use Image.getScaledInstance(...), and then make your ImageIcon from that Image.

Comment: when i try i have a problem with the path or the url !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paint the image in a JPanel as the whole panel. Then whenever the panel is resized, the image will be resized along with it. Here's a quick-n-dirty runnable demo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImgFrame extends JFrame {

    private static BufferedImage IMG;
    static{
        try {
            IMG = ImageIO.read(new File("img/Original_Doge_meme.jpg")); //Replace with your image path
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ImgFrame(){
        add(new ImgPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(500,700);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class ImgPanel extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ImgFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably cleaner to just resize the image. I highly recommend the image resizing utility methods provided by [filthyrichclients](https://java.net/projects/filthyrichclients/sources/svn/content/trunk/StaticEffects/BlurryReflection/src/GraphicsUtilities.java?raw=true).

I actually highly recommend the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132413930) as well, as it was one of the few books that actually demonstrated the power of Swing...

Once you have the code, you will want to call

```
createCompatibleImage(myImage, myWidth,myHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks! But the first answer is better for my case, But i give you upvote and i am going to your different answers and give you upvote, Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it's nice when questioners do that